# Position Div2 Above Div1 With Pure CSS

Tags: html, css

You see the sample code below and the thing I want to do in demo is;
I want to get the secondbar to the top by making some changes in css and secondbar class, without changing html or using javascript. Also, when this happens, the firstbar should scroll down (position:absolute). How can I do that?

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="firstbar"></div>   
  <div class="secondbar">Hi there!</div>
</div>

 .wrap{
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid black;
 }

 .firstbar{
    background:gray;
    height: 70px;
    width:100%;  
  }

  .secondbar{
    font-size:24px;
    color:orange;
    background:yellow;
    width:100%;
  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z14mhoq4/

Comment: Without javascript? Good luck figuring that out...

Comment: Good luck with that !!

Comment: A big question is: "when this happens". Yes, when? How?  What will/should trigger the change?

Comment: If you don't want javascript why tag it with that and jquery?

Comment: @MarcB thank you actually I have to use it for noscript :)

Comment: @Teemu it is noscript customize

Comment: Are you trying to snap the .secondbar to the top of the screen when the user scrolls  below a certain point?

Answer (score 1):

Yup it is very much possible:

```
margin-top:-70px;
```

Add the above line to your second bar.

I admit mine is the cheeky way out. But the other way would be by using the `order` as suggested by Nico O. But as your question specifies you want to make changes in one place only , my answer should suffice

Updated fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/z14mhoq4/2/

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you can do some ordering using [flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and it's [`order` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#order-property).

Here is your example with changes:

```
.wrap {
    border:1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.firstbar {
    background:gray;
    height: 70px;
    flex: 1 0 100%;
    order: 2;
}
.secondbar {
    font-size:24px;
    color:orange;
    background:yellow;
    flex: 1 0 100%;
    order: 1;
}
```

**Demo http://jsfiddle.net/z14mhoq4/1/**

Comment: He doesnt want to change anything in the first bar . But still , great answer +1

Comment: @MohitBhasi thank you for your comment. But to be honest I don't really get what was changed in `.firstbar` what should not have been altered. Did i miss an important point?

Comment: Yup , he mentioned he only wants to make changes in the .secondbar . In your answer , you have added order in firstbar and secondbar

Comment: I think the important restriction was: *without changing html or using javascript*. I don't think it should be a problem to alter the other class as well. But good point, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z14mhoq4/4/) with css3 effect to animate the position using `absolute` position.